# pytest: How to use test class instance variables as fixture params

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to reuse some unit testing functionality. The only variable part is actually the set of test data. Therefore I encapsulate the testing logic in a class and inject the actual test data at object creation.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work with the `@pytest.fixture` decorator.

Some minimal code to reproduce.
This is the common definition of my test class in `define_test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pytest

class TestDemo:
    def __init__(self, _data: list):
        self.__testData = _data

    @pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=self.__testData)
    def fixture(self, request):
        return request.param

    def test(self, fixture):
        foo = fixture
        assert foo is not None
```

Intended usage would be something like this in `use_test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import define_test

data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test1 = define_test.TestDemo(data1)
data2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]
test2 = define_test.TestDemo(data2)
```

Trying to run this code produces

```
define_test.py:9: in TestDemo
    ???
E   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is, that one cannot simply apply the usual OO mechanisms to the `pytest` decorator. It seems as either the decorator is evaluated before even an instance of this class exists or it cannot handle instances at all.

**So what would be the correct way of achieving the goal of reusable tests with variable data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to express this by dynamic parameterization which you can access through the hook `pytest_generate_tests`

there are some [examples in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

This way you can intercept the tests at collection time and inject your own parameterize settings. The hook is called for each test with a `metafunc` object as the argument which exposes a `parameterize` method

The metafunc documentation is [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=metafunc#id75)

It doesn't look to me like you will be able to access instance data, because this code is happening at collect time, before your objects are initialised. But you can access the class object via `metafunc.cls`, so maybe you could have your methods in a superclass, and then subclass this to add specific data cases as class attributes

here is some example code of the kind of thing I am thinking about

a) `pytestfoo.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pytest


class BaseTest:

    def test(self, testparams):
        print("\n", testparams, "\n")
        assert testparams is not None

class TestCaseA(BaseTest):
    testparams = [[1,2,3,4]]

class TestCaseB(BaseTest):
    testparams = [[4,3,2,1]]
```

b) the corresponding `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize("testparams", metafunc.cls.testparams)
```

and a run of these tests using `pytest`

```
pytest -sv pytestfoo.py
========================================================== test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/cms/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/tmp/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/cms/tmp
collected 2 items                                                                                                                       

pytestfoo.py::TestCaseA::test[testparams0] 
 [1, 2, 3, 4] 

PASSED
pytestfoo.py::TestCaseB::test[testparams0] 
 [4, 3, 2, 1] 

PASSED

=========================================================== 2 passed in 0.01s ===========================================================
```

hopefully there is some inspiration here for your own experiments. The pytest docs are showing how to paramaterize with data from the command line, which might be more practically useful than the approach above, but I was trying to follow your lead in defining the data with code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @cms. I will look into these directions.

Comment: @twil you're welcome! I updated to include some example toy code of the approach i was suggesting

Comment: Thanks for the additional code example and for challenging the initial request to solve this with instance attributes. This was only my initial, naive attempt. If there is another/better approach to defer data injection and make the solution extensible this is just as good. Nice example for "give people what they need, not what they want." Now let me try the options....

Comment: Okay, after trying out the solution proposed by @cms I can confirm that it technically fulfils the requirement to intercept test parametrisation at collection time. That's why I mark it as the accepted answer. While digging deeper in the topic I found, that `pytest_generate_tests` will be executed for **each** test in a module. This will result in some extend of conditional code in this function or the need to organise tests in multiple modules. I will need to see, whether this is practical for larger test suites.